# Generate customized exceptions in react

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using EcmaScript 6 for a react app. Customized exception has to be generated while making a connection with server. Is there a way to generate user defined exceptions and handle them separately?

```
connection.socket.onmessage = (action) => {
    try {
     // some action
     dispatch(action)
    } catch (ex) {
      // Server sends message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's more question about JavaScript in general, than about React.
I believe this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) should help you

```
    function UserException(message) {
       this.message = message;
       this.name = "UserException";
    }

    function test() {
        throw new UserException("Some error message");
    }

    try {
        test();
    } catch (e) {
       if (e instanceof UserException) {
          // code for your exception
       } else {
          // all others
       }
    }
```